# Assembly _start function for Windows 10+

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I am trying to make a Compiler and I don't know how to make `_start` function for windows.
Compiler compiles successfully but only for linux, for windows it waits 2 s and exits.

I've tried

```
.globl _WinMain@16
_WinMain@16:
  ; Code here
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-170

Comment: If you don't even put a `ret` in your `_WinMain`, of course it will crash instead of exiting cleanly right away.  (Or a `call ExitProcess`, like how in Linux you have to make an exit system call; in Linux there is no return address.)

Comment: I did this yesterday on 2 am